# iOS Swift - Problems using UICollectionViews with reusable identifier cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

Well, my problem is that I have this App for a Resort and they told me that they would prefer to use Collection Views for displaying a list of items, for example the subsection I am going to add on this post is from a section they call "Wellness" so, there is a list of items that I have added programatically with text, number and a temp image (they don't have the definitive images so...) the point is that my code works perfectly, but I have a problem when I scroll up and down several times I get that the label inside my first cell appears that it doesn't respect my constraints at all.
Here is my code of the view controller with the CollectionView inside.

```
import UIKit

class WellnessViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var introduction: UILabel!

struct cells {
    let number: Int!
    let text: String!
    let image: UIImage!
}
var structArray = [cells]()
var textArray = ["Our Massage offerings incorporate traditional techniques with local ingredients to create a transformative experience.\n Nekupe Express Massage\n Zen Blend Swedish Massage  Alfredo’s Favorite Therapeutic Massage\n Ometepe Couples Massage","Licensed therapists will share their knowledge of Eastern practices to yield extraordinary results for guests.\n Abhyanga (Ayurvedic) Balancing Massage\n Tok Sen Ancient Healing Practice\n Dry Needling with Cranial Sacral Therapy","A treat for the skin, Nekupe offers cleansing and rejuvenating facials for adult women and men that will leave your skin radiant.\n Express 30-minute Facial\n Nekupe Deep Cleansing\n Zen Relaxing Facial \nThe Magnum Facial for Men","Choco Love Cacao Body Masque\n Mombacho Magnifico Salt and Sand Body Masque\n Sweet Tropical Wellness Pineapple Body Masque\n Café Con Amor Coffee Body Treatment\n Super Hydrating Coconut Body Treatment","Nekupe has teamed up with Zen Yoga Nicaragua, a studio located San Juan del Sur, to offer a daily Vinyasa Flow Yoga class on Mirador Deck as well Restorative Yoga, Ashtanga, Yin Yoga, and Power Yoga classes. Additionally, Nekupe offers an annual Yoga Retreat hat features vegetarian meals, spa treatments and one-on-one sessions.","Therapeutic bodywork consultation with Dr. Adam Friedman that focuses on:\n Transformational  Coaching\n Metabolic Conditioning\n Naturopathic Lifestyle and Nutrition Program","Nekupe offers opportunities around the entire reserve for guests to exercise, engage and challenge themselves through physical activity, from cardio and weights to personal training, fitness paths and swimming.\n\nIt features a full-service gym, with a personal trainer (upon request), two professional tennis courts, and mountain biking trails through our diverse landscape. All of the activities are designed for guests with different skills and fitness levels, guaranteeing a good exercise for everyone. Three pools are available for our guests, two of them located at La Residencia Doña Theresita, another one located at Casa Club."]
var imageArray = [UIImage(named: "2.jpg"),UIImage(named: "3.jpg"),UIImage(named: "4.jpg"),UIImage(named: "5.jpg"),UIImage(named: "6.jpg"),UIImage(named: "7.jpg"),UIImage(named: "1.jpg")]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    introduction.text = "OASIS’ central spa location offers nourishing and restorative treatments in our main spa, with three treatment rooms and a zen garden. Satellite treatment spots are located throughout the resort."
    introduction.sizeToFit()
    structArray = [cells(number: 1, text: "Oasis Massage",image: UIImage(named: "2.jpg") ),cells(number: 2, text: "Oasis Specialized Treatments",image: UIImage(named: "3.jpg")),cells(number: 3, text: "Oasis Facials",image: UIImage(named: "4.jpg")),cells(number: 4, text: "Oasis Masques & Body Treatments", image: UIImage(named: "5.jpg")),cells(number: 5, text: "Nekupe Yoga", image: UIImage(named: "6.jpg")),cells(number: 6, text: "Life Coaching", image: UIImage(named: "7.jpg")),cells(number: 7, text: "Nekupe Fitness Center", image: UIImage(named: "1.jpg"))]
    collectionView.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.structArray.count
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WellnessViewCell
    cell.text.text=structArray[indexPath.row].text
    cell.image.image=structArray[indexPath.row].image
    cell.text.sizeToFit()
    return cell
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailWellness", sender: self)
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DetailWellness" {
        let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
        let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath

        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailWellnessViewController
        vc.title = self.structArray[indexPath.row].text
        vc.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]!
        //vc.text = self.textArray[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Please ignore the prepareForSegue, that's a method for passing information to a single view controller that I have next, that's not important in this problem.
And this would be my CollectionView Cell

```
class WellnessViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var text: UILabel!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        image.image=nil
        text.text=nil
    } 
}
```

Well, that's all the code I have, the method inside my collection view cell "prepareForReuse()" people told me that maybe it was because collection views every time we scroll back to top, they do once again the delegate, so maybe that's what my issue was, but it didn't work, now I will show you in the simulator how this works.

[This is how it looks once I open the Wellness Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ruWo.png)

[And this is how it looks when I scroll down and I go back to top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRWff.png)

Anyone knows a solution to this issue, any help would be great!

Comment: why this: `cell.text.sizeToFit()`? have you used constraints?

Comment: In the storyboard I have the label with lines: 0. Because the text inside of it takes more than one line, so this was the only way I could adapt it, I tried with 2 lines but I got the same Issue when I scroll down and returned to the top got the same problem

Comment: Also I have constraints set to the cell, bottom, leading and trailing, with the value of 20 without taking in count the margins

Comment: and top space constraint?

Comment: Try removing text.text = nil from prepareForReuse. This should not be necessary since you are always setting text.text in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: There's no need of it, as I said, the label has text that takes more than one line, so, I only need the bottom, leading and trailing constraints, because if I set a top constraint, the label won't adapt to its content, and actually that's not necessary if you see the images, you'll see that it doesn't respect my constraints at all

Comment: And that piece of code I didn't add it by the time I presented the issue, that was actually a possible solution that I found in another question of stack overflow, but it didn't work, so even if I remove it, it will still be the same result